# proper Similarity measure and clustering algorithm for binary data

Tags: clustering, binary-data, similarities

data sample as follow : interest to find clusters of similar users, pages number around 100 pages. users around 1000 , i would like to know what are proper Similarity/dis. measure can used in this data set along with clustering algorithm that has good recommend here ?
Value 0 refer to that user never visit opposite page otherwise 1.

```
                                           Page view 
              page A      Page B      Page C     page D    Page E ...   
User1      1            0                  0                1 
user2      0            0                  1                0                              
user3      1            0                  1                0                   
    ....
```

Thanks for any suggestion note

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are may "proper" metrics.

Which one works best depends on your data and scenario. They have slightly different semantics, e.g. Jaccard was originally built to measure the similarity of Ecosystems.

These metrics are commonly used with hierarchical clustering.

Comment: According to this data set ... 

Are you mean sir Jaccard similarity its recommended for measures the similarity , and hierarchical algorithms its recommended for clustering ?

Comment: It is an *option* that you should try. I don't know if it works. Every data set is different! You need to *experiment*, clustering is all about experimenting.